# Vim: Delete all text surrounded by a start and an end

Tags: regex, vim, text, plaintext

Say I've got this:

```
    \item[1]\footnote{«footnote blah blah»}
footnote blah blah.
    \item[2]\footnote{«blah blah footnote»}
random text
    \item[3]\footnote{«this is not»}
more random text
```

I want to quickly delete \footnote{*} (that includes \footnote{«footnote blah blah»} \footnote{«blah blah footnote»} and \footnote{«this is not»}, but not \item[x] or the lines below that. How is this achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: take the text in your question, you just need `%s/\\footnote{.*//`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most accurate way would be to use:

```
:%s/\\footnote{.\{-}}//g
```

This will delete footnote and everything in between the braces.  Using `{.*}` will delete everything up to the last brace even if it is outside of the footnote brace.

Answer (score 0):

In escape mode

```
:1,$s/\\footnote{.*}//g
```

Comment: You can always use `%` in stead of `1,$`